# codeigniter $this->db->query JOIN WHERE not working

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

This my screenshot problem I have

[image: This my screenshot problem I have]

I have the following codes in my view.

```
$jumlah = $this->db->query("
            SELECT * FROM actor 
            JOIN film_actor ON film_actor.actor_id=actor.actor_id
            JOIN film ON film.film_id=film_actor.film_id
            JOIN film_category ON film_category.film_id=film.film_id
            JOIN category ON category.category_id=film_category.category_id
            WHERE first_name like $u->first_name AND last_name like $u->last_name");
            ?>
```

why my query not working? I think I have done with that code, but why I am getting error message.

Sorry, i can't describe my problem so detail, but i have image for describe that.

Comment: give values like `$u->first_name` in single quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$array = array('first_name' => $u->first_name, 'last_name' => $u->last_name);
$jumlah = $this->db->select('*')->from('actor');
      $this->db->join('film_actor', 'film_actor.actor_id=actor.actor_id');
      $this->db->join('film', 'film.film_id=film_actor.film_id');
      $this->db->join('film_category', 'film_category.film_id=film.film_id');
      $this->db->join('category', 'category.category_id=film_category.category_id ');
      $this->db->like($array); // WHERE `first_name` LIKE '%$u->first_name%'  AND  `last_name` LIKE '%$u->last_name%'
```